# Matrix within a matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm looking to make something like this: [image]

I can only create a matrix on one entry so far. How would one do this?

Muchos gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{pNiceMatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & \Cdots &  X_{1n} \\
X_{21} & \Block{3-3}<\Large>{B} \\
\Vdots \\
X_{1n} \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix[{2-2}{4-4}][xshift=-1ex,extra-height=-1ex]
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Only `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
  x_{11} & \begin{matrix} x_{12} & \dots & x_{1n} \end{matrix} \\
  \begin{matrix} x_{21} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n1} \end{matrix}  &
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \hspace*{-\arraycolsep}
  \phantom{x_{11}} & \phantom{x_{11}} & \phantom{x_{11}}
  \hspace*{-\arraycolsep}
  \\
  & \raisebox{-0.2\height}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE$B$} & \\
  & &
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]